# I want to fetch multiple data and return multiple records from database and convert that to json format?is this write way or not?

Tags: java

I want to fetch multiple data and  return multiple records from database and convert that to json format?is this write way or not?

also i want to set multiple data in bean class to that i can change it to json using gson lib.?
whic on is better ??

//WifiDb.java

public class WifiDb {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   db d=new db();

   String s="charreendigarh";

     List jsonString=d.getInfo(s);
    System.out.println("hello"+jsonString);
   if(jsonString != null)
   {
       System.out.println("jsonString::"+jsonString);    
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
       JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();

       //   System.out.println("size "+jsonString);
       System.out.println("\n==> Iterator Example...");
       Iterator itr = jsonString.iterator();

       while (itr.hasNext())
       {

           JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
           formDetailsJson.put("wifi_address",itr.next() );
           jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
       }
    //   GetAndSetWifiInfo gt=new GetAndSetWifiInfo(0, " Records Founds");
  //     responseDetailsJson.put("", gt);

       responseDetailsJson.put("data", jsonArray);
       System.out.println(""+responseDetailsJson);

   }
   else
    {
                GetAndSetWifiInfo gt=new GetAndSetWifiInfo(1, "No Records Founds");
                 Gson gson = new Gson();

                String gsn = gson.toJson(gt);
                System.out.println("gsn message is" + gsn);

    }
}
```

}

2. db.java file

class db {

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";


List Addres_name_list=new ArrayList();

List getInfo(String address) {
         System.out.println("address is ::"+address);
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "select * from wifidb_address where wifi_state='" + address + " '";
        System.out.println("sql"+sql);
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
            while (rs.next())

            {
                String wifi_address = rs.getString("wifi_address");
                System.out.println("wifi_address is:"+wifi_address);
                Addres_name_list.add(wifi_address);



            }
            //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
        }
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException se) {
    } finally {
        //finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }// nothing we can do
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }//end finally try
    }//end try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    return Addres_name_list;

}
```

}

Comment: I personally like GSON a lot. I think it's a good choice of a library to convert to JSON

Comment: yes it is to some extent. But there are logical errors in your code like closing connection/statement twice...

Comment: i want result in this format but can't find the proper answer  {"message":"Records Founds","status":0,"data":[{"id":12345,"wifi_address":"Sector 5, Panchkula, Haryana, India","wifi_unique_id":"1234567","wifi_name":"BSNLNET","operator_name":"bsnl","password":"test12345","offset_location":"50","updated_date_time":"2038-01-19 03:14:07"}]}

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experiences with Jackson to perform a direct mapping using an Object mapper. I usually build JSON conversion methods into my objects directly:

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    public class MyObject {

      private String obtainedSubscription;

      public String getObtainedSubscription() {
        return obtainedSubscription;
      }

      public void setObtainedSubscription(String obtainedSubscription) {
        this.obtainedSubscription = obtainedSubscription;
      }

      /**
       * Turn into a JSON string.
       */
      public String toJSONString() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);

        return jsonValue;
      }

  /**
   * Import and object from a JSON string
   */
  public static MyObject fromJSONString(String jsonString) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    return mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyObject.class);
  }  
}
```